# Trying to Calculate Qty on Hand and Value on hand with multiple shipments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, I have an Acquisitions table (Incoming) and Invoice Table (Outgoing) I am trying to calculate the Value on Hand by taking the AVG dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqPrice * the QtyOnHand which is figured taking Incoming - Outgoing.  When I add a line item on the Acquisitions table that has a different cost for the same item, the AVG is not grouping and showing instead two line items example below.  The shipment side works fine with multiple line items...

```
Product  QtyIn  QtyOut   On_Hand   AVGPrice   Value_OnHand 
Screws     100      30        70    25.0000      1750.0000 
Nuts        50      10        40    40.0000      1600.0000 
Nuts       100      10        90    50.0000      4500.0000 
Bolts      100      20        80    100.000      8000.0000
```

.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        dbo.tblProduct.Product ,
        SUM(DISTINCT dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqQuantity) AS QtyIN ,
        SUM(DISTINCT dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.InvQuantity) AS QtyOut ,
        SUM(DISTINCT dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqQuantity)
        - SUM(DISTINCT dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.InvQuantity) AS On_Hand ,
        dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqPrice ,
        dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqPrice
        * ( SUM(DISTINCT dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqQuantity)
            - SUM(DISTINCT dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.InvQuantity) ) AS Value_Hand
FROM    dbo.tblAcq
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblAcqDetail ON dbo.tblAcq.acqID = dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblProduct ON dbo.tblAcqDetail.ProductID = dbo.tblProduct.ProductID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceDetail ON dbo.tblProduct.ProductID = dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.ProductID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblInvoice ON dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.tblInvoice.InvoiceID
GROUP BY dbo.tblProduct.Product ,
        dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

To be mathematically accurate, you should not be using `SUM(DISTINCT fieldname)`, but just `SUM(fieldname)`.  Otherwise, it will eliminate entries that happen to have the same quantity.

For that matter, you shouldn't be using `DISTINCT` at the beginning of your query either, `GROUP BY` already handles that.

If you believe you have duplicate rows being returned by your JOINs (which you shouldn't really if you're doing it right), wrap them in a subquery using `DISTINCT` before trying to aggregate.

As an example, a subquery to eliminate duplicates can be written like so:

```
SELECT
    Product ,
    SUM(AcqQuantity) AS QtyIN ,
    SUM(InvQuantity) AS QtyOut ,
    SUM(AcqQuantity)
    - SUM(InvQuantity) AS On_Hand ,
    AcqPrice ,
    AcqPrice
    * ( SUM(AcqQuantity)
        - SUM(InvQuantity) ) AS Value_Hand
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
          dbo.tblProduct.Product ,
          dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqQuantity,
          dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.InvQuantity,
          dbo.tblAcqDetail.AcqPrice
      FROM
          dbo.tblAcqDetail
          INNER JOIN dbo.tblProduct ON dbo.tblAcqDetail.ProductID = dbo.tblProduct.ProductID
          INNER JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceDetail ON dbo.tblProduct.ProductID = dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.ProductID
          INNER JOIN dbo.tblInvoice ON dbo.tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.tblInvoice.InvoiceID ) productInfo
GROUP BY Product, AcqPrice
```

Comment: I tried without the distinct and it was returning multiple rows for the same product.

Comment: I cannot figure out why.  The rows are not duplicated it is simply not grouping or summing them correctly. See the output of the table above.  If I wrap in a DISTINCT as a subquery still not working.

Comment: @user2245667: try removing the `tblAcq` table from the JOIN - it isn't being used anywhere.  It would also help if you can post some sample data for each table separately...

Comment: @user2245667: updated with an example on using DISTINCT in a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Basing on PinnyM's answer, you don't need `DISTINCT`, I re-write your query as following using table alias:

```
SELECT
        P.Product ,
        SUM( AcD.AcqQuantity) AS QtyIN ,
        SUM( InD.InvQuantity) AS QtyOut ,
        SUM( AcD.AcqQuantity)
        - SUM( InD.InvQuantity) AS On_Hand ,
        AcD.AcqPrice ,
        AcD.AcqPrice
        * ( SUM(AcD.AcqQuantity)
            - SUM( InD.InvQuantity) ) AS Value_Hand
FROM    dbo.tblAcq Ac
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblAcqDetail  AcD ON Ac.acqID = AcD.AcqID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblProduct P ON AcD.ProductID = P.ProductID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceDetail InD  ON P.ProductID = InD.ProductID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblInvoice Inv ON InD.InvoiceID = Inv.InvoiceID
GROUP BY P.Product ,
         AcD.AcqPrice
```

By reading this query, I don't understand why you need table `dbo.tblInvoice`, it is not part of aggregation. 
**The reason you still see different product is because you group by two columns `P.Product, AcD.AcqPrice`, not only Product**, in your return result you can see their combination is unique.